# How many different $n$-bit Gray-code-like cycles are there?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, coding-theory

**The Question:** How many different $n$-bit Gray-code-like cycles are there?

It just needs some clarification:

$i)$ The original $n$-bit Gray code is now considered as a cycle of all $n$-bit binary numbers, which satisfies the *Gray* property. So are *$n$-bit Gray-code-like cycles*.

$ii)$ For convenience, let $n > 1$.

$iii)$ By *different cycles*, I exclude the difference made from rotation and reflection.

This problem is posed by myself out of curiosity. By permuting the bits, it is proved that there are at least $\dfrac{n!}{2}$ different cycles. Is that the answer?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: For $n = 2$, there are $2 > \frac{n!}{2}$ Gray code cycles, viz. $00 \to 01 \to 11 \to 10 \to 00$ and $00 \to 10 \to 11 \to 01 \to 00$

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I forgot to mention reflection. I've updated $iii)$. Actually, the factor $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is from this exclusion.

Comment: For styling the question, note that there is support for numbered lists with proper indentation, so that you don't have to use artificial things like `$ii)$`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) has to say about the matter:

> Hamiltonicity of the hypercube is tightly related to the theory of Gray codes. More precisely there is a bijective correspondence between the set of $n$-bit cyclic Gray codes and the set of Hamiltonian cycles in the hypercube $Q_n$.

There is a reference to a 1963 paper by W. H. Mills in Proc. AMS.

Comment: Actually, only the referred paper of this paper helps me out a bit. At least, I know the answer is not so simple and way more than $\dfrac{n!}{2}$ when $n$ goes large. Anyway, thank you!